# how the stack frame works？

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, callstack

i am reading the csapp and some codes (x86-64) confuse me.

the book says "pushq %rbp" equals :

```
    subq $8,%rsp 
    movq %rbp,(%rsp)
```

The c code is :

```
  long P(long x,long y)
  {
      long u = Q(y);
      long v = Q(x);

      return u + v;
  }
```

And the a part of the assembly code the book gives is :

```
    pushq %rbp 
    pushq %rbx
    subq $8,%rsp
```

The 'subq' confuse me.

Why it is like this?

Answer (score 2):

Stack is a block of memory which grows down. There is a point in memory indicated by `rsp`/`esp` register which is a stack top. All memory above it is occupied by things placed on stack and all memory below it is free.

If you want to put something on stack you need to decrease `rsp` register (that is what `sub` instruction does) by number of bytes you need and `rsp` will point now to the newly reserver area you needed.

Lets look at this simple example:

`rsp` points to address 100. As said - whole memory above address 100 is used, and memory below 100 is free. So if you need 4 bytes you decrease `rsp` by 4 so it points to 96. As you have just decreased `rsp` you are aware that memory cells 96, 97, 98 and 99 are yours and you can use them. When you need more bytes on stack, then you again can decrease `rsp` to get it more.

There are two ways puting things on stack. 
 1. you can decrease `rsp` as shown above.
 2. you can use `push` instruction which does exactly the same but in one step: `push rax` will decrease `rsp` by 8 bytes (size of `rax` register) and then will save its value in reserved area.

Sometimes also `rbp` register is being used to operate on stack.
If you need a bigger area on stack, for example for local variables, you reserve required amount on stack and then you save current `rsp` value into `rbp`. So `rbp` is a kind of bookmark remembering where your area is. Then you can `push` more things on stack, without loosing information where the allocated area was.

Before leaving function all things placed on stack need to be taken from it. It is done by `pop` instruction which is opposite to `push` - takes value from stack and moves it to register and then increases `rsp`. Or you can just increase `rsp` if you do not need to restore register values.

Comment: x86-64 uses 8-byte stack "slots".  You never want to misalign the stack so you'd always adjust it by a multiple of 8.  (Or more usually to reach a 16-byte alignment boundary.)  Also, the RBP-as-bookmark analogy works better if you consider allocating a *variable* amount of space, like `alloca` or a C99 variable-length-array, or `and $-32, %rsp` to align the stack for AVX.  With a known number of pushes or other allocations, compilers still optimize away the frame pointer because they know how far they moved RSP, and thus what the current offset to any given location is.

Comment: I wonder why the code in this book use the "pushq" and "subq" at the same time, the "pushq"  like you said : "you can use push instruction which does exactly the same but in one step: push rax will decrease rsp by 8 bytes (size of rax register) and then will save its value in reserved area." since the "pushq" already decrease the RSP why use the "subq" again? now i just wonder the "subq" here is used for what? @MichałWalenciak

Comment: It uses push when it wants to save the value of a register on the stack and it uses sub when it wants to reserve stack space that is uninitialized. The uninitialized space is typically written to later. Sub is also used to align the stack to a multiple of 16, in which case the space may not be used.